# Unable to install hummus npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ibm-cloud

I was trying to install hummus npm module. But it is giving me a list of errors. Can someone tell me what causes this issue if I have installed before? I am using Windows 7.

```
> C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp>npm install hummus           
> C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus>
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
> Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program   Files\nodejs\node.e
>     xe  C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-g
>     yp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build -- module=C:\Users\hmudunuri\Des
>     ktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus\binding\hummus.node -- module_name=hummus
>     -- module_path=C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus\bindi
>     ng' (1)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>  (C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desk
>     top\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus\node_modules\node-pre- gyp\lib\util\compile    .js:83:29)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit  (internal/chi
>     ld_process.js:211:5)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"   "C:\\Users\\hmud
>     unuri\\Desktop\\encryptionapp\\node_modules\\hummus\\node_modules\\node-pre-
> gyp\    \bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd  C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>     Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe   C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\e
>     ncryptionapp\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js  
> configure --
>     fallback-to-build --  module=C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules
>     \hummus\binding\hummus.node --module_name=hummus --   module_path=C:\Users\hmudunur
>     i\Desktop\encryptionapp\node_modules\hummus\binding' (1)
>     npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>     npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program   Files\\nodejs\\
>     node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "hummus"
>     npm ERR! node v4.5.0
>     npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
>     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>     npm ERR! hummus@1.0.60 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>     npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the hummus@1.0.60 install script  node-pre-gyp install -- fall
>     back-to-build npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hummus package,
>     npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>     npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>     npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>     npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project  with:
>     npm ERR!     npm bugs hummus
>     npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR!     npm owner ls hummus
>     npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above. 
>     npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
>     npm ERR! C:\Users\hmudunuri\Desktop\encryptionapp\npm'
```

Comment: Have you set the msvs_version property?

Comment: have you tried `npm install hummus --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 1):

Remove and reinstall hummus.
remove with

```
npm remove hummus
```

and install with

```
npm install hummus
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into basic native module compilation issues.
Follow the steps for PC environment in:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm i hummus --unsafe-perm 
sudo npm i hummus-recipe --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an existing project check the version of `hummus` in `package.json`. In my case the project was locked at `1.0.107`, which didn't install and errored in similar fashion to OP's question.

Pointing at the latest (`1.0.110` at the time of writing), did the trick.